# How to make an discord js bot to message in dm someone after he gets a certain role

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, discord, bots

My code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client(); 
const prefix = '$';

client.once('ready' , () => {
    console.log('M-am trezit din morti!');
});

client.on('message' , message  =>{
   if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

   const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
   const command= args.shift().toLowerCase();

   if(command === 'about'){
       
   }else if(command === 'troll'){
       const messages = ["Esti un ratat!!", "Akatsuki este cel mai tare!", "Lui Tobi ii plac baietii!", "Invata sa joci, noobule!" , "Esti pe langa cu jocul!", "Cum naiba ai ajuns in factiunea asta?"]

       const randomMessage = messages[Math.floor(Math.random() * messages.length)];
    
       message.channel.send(randomMessage)
   }
});

client.login('notgonnashowit');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
    client.on("guildMemberUpdate", (oldMember, newMember) => {
      // when Member is updated check if the Member has a role by ID
      if (newMember._roles.includes("ROLE ID HERE")){
          // then DM them
          newMember.send('message to dm');
        } 
    });
```

To use the above you have to turn on SERVER MEMBERS INTENT in the bot dashboard:

[image: Like this]

Comment: you could also assign the role and then use `.then()` to send a message afterwards. That might be easier then adding a new event listener.

Comment: How do  i add it?It doesnt seem to work.When i put something there it just doesnt work